# Effect of "table_properties" property for Delta Live Tables

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables

I have the following code:

```
@dlt.table(
    name="ingested_data",
    comment="Ingest the table",
    table_properties={
        "quality": "raw", "name": "property_name"
    }
)
```

I am confused what the `table_properties` dictionary does in practice? I have seen no effect of the key-value pairs. [Here](https://docs.databricks.com/delta-live-tables/python-ref.html#python-delta-live-tables-properties) is the list of the accepted keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table properties are used for two things:

1. Defining specific configurations that will be used by the underlying engine - they are listed in [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/delta-live-tables/properties.html#delta-live-tables-table-properties).  Like, `pipelines.reset.allowed` defines if it's allowed to perform a reset on the given table (it's good idea to disable it on the table that holds data ingested from Kafka), or `pipelines.autoOptimize.zOrderCols` defines a list of columns that will be used in `OPTIMIZE ZORDER BY <cols>`.
2. Allow to specify arbitrary table properties/metadata, like, data quality level (`raw` in your example`), tags, etc. that could be used when searching for tables in UI.

1st kind of usage happens often in practice, while 2nd is optional.